# Is One Week Friends manga still on going?

Tags: manga-production, one-week-friends

Finished the anime and very curious on whats gonna happen next. Is the manga complete or is it still on going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is still ongoing according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Week_Friends). At top right of the page under "Original run", it says "January 21, 2012 – ongoing".

Sometimes, Wikipedia doesn't update the information or the status is left like that when the series is on a long unexplained hiatus. Just to be sure, in the Volumes section of that page, it says that the release date for Volume 7 is April 22, 2015, which shows that the next volumes is in the works.

Also, [Manga-Updates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=73195) says the same thing under "Status in Country of Origin" (*6 Volumes (Ongoing)*)

According to a post on [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-07-21/one-week-friends-manga-final-volume-ships-in-april-2015/.76876) provided by [Torisuda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14057/is-one-week-friends-manga-still-on-going/14058?noredirect=1#comment18069_14058), Volume 7 is the last one.

> The sixth compiled volume of Matcha Hazuki's Isshūkan Friends. (One Week Friends) manga is announcing on Tuesday (26/07/2014) that the seventh and final volume of the manga will be released in Japan on April 22, 2015.

Comment: That long? Hahaha.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel i did expand the answer cause i wasn't very happy it being so short. it just gives a bit of a head up if you use wikipedia to look to see if something is ongoing or not

Comment: [MangaFox](http://mangafox.me/manga/isshuukan_friends/) is still on Volume 5. Volume 6 hasn't been translated?

Comment: @NatsuDragneel Manga-Updates lists "Latest Release(s)" with the latest being v.5 c.22 by Sense-Scans, which seems to be the first chapter of Volume 5, the Volume 6/7 info is the official japanese release information but it seems Manga-Updates only lists scanlation progress in that section

Comment: So it'll take a long time to release Vol 6 its been months since Vol 5 was release I think.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel more or less, though official translation releases are just as slow as Vampire Knight Volume 19 was released in May 24, 2013 but it's was released in English this year.

Comment: [This Anime News Network post](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-07-21/one-week-friends-manga-final-volume-ships-in-april-2015/.76876) says Volume 7 will be the last volume and that it will come out in April 2015. But apparently the manga has been licensed (though I can't find out by whom), so a lot of the scanlators have stopped working on it.

Comment: @Torisuda i've altered my last sentence with the information you have provided. i have left out the licensed part for now as the link you provided only talks about the anime's licencing, you free to edit in info on English licensing of the manga if you find a link indicating who has it

Comment: @Memor-X I couldn't find out who has it. MangaFox (which I can't link to) claims it's licensed, but they said the same of Banana no Nana, which I'm 99% sure isn't licensed. I was kind of hoping someone who did know would see my comment and tell us all. (BTW, +1 for your answer.)

Comment: @NatsuDragneel Remember, you can accept this answer by clicking the green check mark if it answered your question. You and Memor-X both get reputation if you accept.